# Socket connection inside route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to clean up my express node app by maintaining all of the socket.io functionality inside express routes, or router pages (relying on a question answered here: [Nodejs include socket.io in router page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500922/nodejs-include-socket-io-in-router-page)). For some unknown reason, no socket connection ever opens (no "success" is ever logged).

```
//app.js
server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
app.get('/', function(req,res){
   routes.index(req,res,app,server);  
 });
```

With my routes.index looking like this:

```
//routes.index
var socketio = require('socket.io');
exports.index = function(req,res,app,server){
  var io = socketio.listen(server);
  server.listen(3000);
  console.log("routed correctly?"); //yes, it is routed correctly. 
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("success");
  });
  res.render('index');
};
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I realized I shouldn't do it, but I still wasn't sure why that particular configuration didn't work.

The problem I had was that I didn't realize that the socket needed to be opened from a client.js before my server found a 'connection'.

So to fix it, I only needed to write:

```
//client.js
var socket = io.socket();
```

and make sure that

```
res.render('index');
```

appears before  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {...})

But it still looks messy, I'll try something like session.socket.io or even express.io.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this makes much sense since each time somebody requests `exports.index` you are recreating a new socket.io server. Socket.io is meant to be a communication layer that lives along side of routes.

Answer (score 1):

According to that answer this is exactly what you **DON'T** want to do.

With this logic, each time your `/` route is hit, you will add another listener for the `connect` event.  This should only be done once, outside of your route logic.  In addition, your server is also attempting to listen on port 3000 multiple times.

If you want to access the socket for a particular users web session, you will need to associate the socket received from the `connect` event with that users session using something like [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) (there are multiple libraries doing this - this is just one example)