# How to modularize socket.io to multiple pages

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io and express.
Is it possible to initialize the socket inside routes/index.js in an express application?

I tried requiring app.js and listened on that, but it didn't work.

```
var app = require('../app.js');
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

If the above is not possible, how can I initialize the io variable inside app.js and then use it in index.js?

What I am trying to understand is how to modularize socket.io

Let's say that I have an website where two pages uses sockets. I don't want to put all code for both of them inside app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It was not exactly what I was looking for, but it'll do.

[Nodejs include socket.io in router page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500922/nodejs-include-socket-io-in-router-page?rq=1)

As said in above link.

```
//app.js
var sockets = require('./sockets');
sockets.socketServer(app, server);


// sockets.js
var socketio = require('socket.io');
exports.socketServer = function (app, server) {
  var io = socketio.listen(server);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ...
  });
};
```

Currently all emits are now sent to socket.js. But I would have liked to divide it into multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **server** object in listen of **io**.  Try this.

```
    var app = require('../app.js');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });

    var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

    io.on("connection",function(socket){
        console.log("Application connected");
        socket.on('disconnect',function(){
            console.log("Application Disconnected");
        });

        socket.on('some-event',function(meetup){
            //do something
            io.emit('some-new-event-to-notify-client',passSomeData);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I get an error when trying to use app. It says
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);  
       ^  
TypeError: undefined is not a function  
(^ is pointing at set)

Comment: Could you please paste your app.js, let me see what is in there.